# Custom Button with JQuery

Tags: custom-button, jquery

I have a custom button (which is a list button) and I'm requiring JQuery by the following code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js")}
```

It's working fine! The only problem is that it's taking too long to execute. If I click on the button right after the page is loaded, it doesn't run and I have to click again. The other standard Salesforce buttons work just as fast as when I do not require JQuery for the custom ones.

Does anyone know if there is a faster way to get JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by adding the minimized version of jQuery as a local resource and then make sure to set jQuery.noConflict();

Something like this:

```
 <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryFiles, 'js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js')}"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
   j$(document).ready(function(){
            //document ready code
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Yep, thanks, I'm using noConflict and the min file and still I get the same result.

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery as a local resource? Also, use something like firebug to see how long each resource is taking to load.

Comment: Hi, I tried to load it as a local resource but I coudn't get it to work, it says that $Resource is not available.

Comment: That's what I found so far https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KRuxAAG

Comment: Also, I realized that Salesforce already imports jQuery, therefore I could use it without calling mine (what is not a good practice, by the way)